# Allow access only for some Mac Ids

Tags: authentication, mac-address

There is an application which shows a login page. However, I do not want people to login through any machine. I want to restrict login to a few Mac Ids. Is there a way to do this?

There is probably a way to get the MacId from a java applet or ActiveX control, but how would a call which spoofs the MacId in a modified Applet be prevented?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent the spoofing of a MAC. Your attempt will help restrict ordinary users, but will not prevent an attacker from accessing it.

Comment: To give a real world analogy of the problem: Imagine you own a club that only lets people named Scott in, if when Mr. Deters here tries to go in he just says his name is Scott Chamberlain the bouncer at the door will happily let him in. You have no way of verifying the identity of a MAC address the computer gave you is the real address. Now if the bouncer asked for some form of ID from a trusted 3rd party that you knew would not give out fake IDs (*client certificates*) then the problem would be solved.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain What prevents a user from transferring the client certificate to a different machine?

Comment: @user93353 Nothing, but they have to have access to the machine to clone it. You don't need access to the source machine to clone a MAC address, just observe it's existence on the network.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain My usecase to make a valid user use it only from one machine. So obviously client certificates won't work.